# I cant import data from another big sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

Im having trouble importing data from my another sheet. Its quite big, has over 500 rows and to 100 columns. (I dont know if thats important but it has about 50 sheets, I want to import from first biggest one)

`Importhtml` and `importdata` take too long to load and then say that source is too big.

But what I want is `importrange` and that says internal error all the time.

Do you have any advice how can I import my data? Maybe even how to change source so it can be imported from?

[Sheet I want import to](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_nh7gdUSUUQg8YRCvNOntpKNAz9HEEl9NIc5ESzfflg/edit?usp=drivesdk)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to use is [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

```
=IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXXXX";"Prices!A1:AJ")
```

*(where `XXXXXXXXX` is the sheet ID)*

---

***Pro tip***

> *But what I want is `importrange` and that says internal error all the time.*

A good practice is to **first link the two sheets by using a very small range** like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXXXX";"Prices!A1:A3")
```

[image]

and **then change the range to meet your needs**

```
=IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXXXX";"Prices!A1:AJ")
```

Comment: (Ok, so I missed sheet name, thanks. But why does it load so long? Any way to make it faster?) Never mind, had to stop other. Still takes 10 seconds but thats fine

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. *"But why does it load so long?"* That depends on the power of your machine. It also has to do with the images you keep in the first column. If you were to omit those, the sheet would load much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try coupler.io.
It has a free plan and allows to COPY the data from one spreadsheet to another on a schedule. It means you can split your calculations, make heavy ones on one spreadsheet and then copy results to the one when you work with them.

It also allows to import from CRM, financial apps etc, but your case is covered with GSheet -> Gsheet import.